# Grab keyboard input in Linux

Tags: linux, keyboard, raspberry-pi

I have a Linux environment (custom buildroot on Rpi2) which logs in in a console (no X).

On powerup my Qt5 console application is started, and this reacts to a keypress. I mean, when the user presses a key, the application does something. There is nothing to show on video, in most cases there isn't any monitor connected.

The problem is the keys pressed are shown on the "screen" anyway so the user is actually typing a command! Very bad.

My application is run in the background from a `/etc/init.d/S*` script. This is because I don't know another way to start it without blocking the following scripts.

The goal is to capture (or "grab") every key pressed while the application is running.

Comment: Does your application actually respond to keypresses, and the only problem is the characters echo'ed to the screen? Or is the application failing to see the keyboard activity?

Comment: Yes, the application reacts correcly. The only problem is the echo.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution seems to be, just to re-direct the standard output into the file like this:

```
[me@linuxbox me]$ your_program_whatever > file_list.txt
```

Your program is executed and the results are written in a file named file_list.txt, no results appear on the display.

Comment: Just tried. Of course the output from the application is redirected to the file, but I still have the echos of the key pressed on the screen. I'm afraid about launching the application in background which leads to show the prompt on the screen.